# Kendo Upload Keep sort (Sync?)

Tags: jquery, file, file-upload, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I am using "kendoUpload" on a website.

People use it to Upload photos from holiday albums.

My current code

```
$("#files").kendoUpload({
    async: {
        saveUrl: "/assets/php/upload.php",
        removeUrl: "remove",
        autoUpload: true
    },
    complete: function(){
        alert('Success!');
    }
});
```

This code works fine.

How do I keep the sorting?

I do not understand how the syncronous (is that what I need?) method works...

Kendo API: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/upload

Comment: what do you mean by `How do I keep the sorting?`

Comment: I mean: I want to upload 3 photos (photo1: 3mb, photo2: 2mb, photo3: 500kb) ...because these photos come from an album they need to be uploaded in the order I chose them. When I use the async method photo3 will be uploaded first (because it takes the quickest due to the filesize etc.).

Comment: No, the saveurl is called for each file that is uploaded in async order (fastest first). I fixed it with the bulk finally will post an answer